# how parse this json data to object?

Tags: .net, json, rest

I've a simple json like:

```
{
"values": [
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    },
    {
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2",
        "key3": "value3"
    }
]
}
```

And my object structure is like that:

```
[DataMember]
public List<KeyValues> values { get; set; }
```

Inside KeyValues, i only have a Dictionary:

```
[DataMember]
public Dictionary<string, string> values { get; set; }
```

The list is filled with 2 objects but the Dictionary still empty.

How can i parse the objects inside the array to my Dictionary?

Thanks in advance.

edit:

```
  [Route("test")]
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage testPost([FromBody] TestObject test)
    {
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Please include your attempted code

Comment: Did you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10274850/net-json-serialization-how-to-have-a-datacontract-as-a-member-of-another-datac?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

It's not a Dictionary that you're passing in. It's an array of objects.  I'd change the Json to

```
{
"values": [
    {
        key: "key1", value: "value1",
        key:  "key2", value:"value2",
         key: "key3", value:"value3"
    },
    {
         key: "key1", value:"value1",
         key: "key2", value:"value2",
         key: "key3", value:"value3"
    }
]
}

}
```

That would then map to the following class structure:

```
public class Value
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Value> values { get; set; }
}
```

This may suffice for you to work with.  If you really wanted a dictionary you could look into creating a custom Json converter (e.g. inherit JsonConverter)